# Is there any order in Task.async_stream|>Stream.drop_while?

Tags: elixir

I have a pipeline which looks like

```
digits
|> Task.async_stream(__MODULE__, :filter, [s, values], timeout: :infinity)
|> Stream.drop_while(fn {_, k} -> k == :contradiction or k == [] end)
|> Stream.take(1)
```

is there any order defined here? Or simply the results of the first `filter` that returns not satisfying the while condition will be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.async_stream` [has an option](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/5-options) for this: `ordered: true | false`. If it's set to true, the results will be in the same order as the input list. When it's false, the results will be in the order the tasks finish. The value of this option defaults to `true`, so in your code the results will be in the same order as the input list.

```
iex(1)> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] |> Task.async_stream(fn x -> :timer.sleep(x * 100); x end) |> Enum.to_list
[ok: 5, ok: 4, ok: 3, ok: 2, ok: 1]
iex(2)> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] |> Task.async_stream(fn x -> :timer.sleep(x * 100); x end, ordered: false) |> Enum.to_list
[ok: 1, ok: 2, ok: 3, ok: 4, ok: 5]
```